# Upgrade to 12.04 failed. Boot into command line window and cant boot with live usb.

Tags: 12.04, boot, command-line, grub2, live-usb

I started an upgrade to 12.04 but stalled during install. Now, the system boots directly into command window where I must sign in. I tried creating a bootable USB (no CD drive installed) with unetbootin and Universal USB Installer, but the system do not boot to USB first - goes directly to hard drive. I tried accessing the grub menu with all suggested commands (ex holding shift, F1, Esc, F10, F12 etc etc etc) but none worked. How can I install the new version 12.04 LTS from USB? Is there any way to install from command line? Or how can I access GRUB settings from command?

Please please please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)  to repair you grub , fo doing so you have to bett ubuntu live usb or dvd and after booting click on try-ubuntu.

When desktop screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+t  for opening terminal and run the follwing commands into the terminal -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

After that the boot-repair window will appear ,in that select Recommended repair option . After completion restart your pc .it will be fixed.

hope it will work.